# Why doesn't res/menu folder exist on new project creation?

Tags: android

I am watching a udemy training series on Android. And for many of the videos, when he creates a new project there is a `res/menu` folder. In it, there are xml files like a `menu_main.xml`. However, when I launch a new project on Android Studio, there is no `res/menu` folder at all. Am I missing something? Why do I have to create it manually?

In the video, it has the following in menu_main.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Did you create a project with an activity?

Comment: Yes of course. One was a blank activity and the other was a login activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

The trainer in the video is using a different version of Android Studio than you are, or you did not set up your project in exactly the same manner (e.g., you chose a different activity template).

> Why do I have to create it manually?

In the version of Android Studio that you are using, for the activity templates that you chose (e.g., "Blank Activity"), the templates do not employ an action bar, `Toolbar`, or anything else that involves a menu resource.

Comment: Assuming I am using the latest version of Android Studio and for sure he is using an older version of Android Studio, how can I generate the content for main_menu.xml? There is no way for anyone to remember all the data in that file.

Comment: @Donato: "how can I generate the content for main_menu.xml?" -- you are welcome to create a new menu resource (e.g., right-click over your project tree and choose New > Android resource file from the context menu). From there, you are welcome to define new menu items, whether via XML or, on newer versions of Android Studio, via a drag-and-drop UI. If Udemy is out of date, and Udemy is not providing written instructions to accompany the video, that is Udemy's problem.

Comment: Yes you are right. There is a gui that allows you to drag and drop menu items into the menu, although you need to create the menu through xml first  (since dragging and dropping menu in design doesn't do anything).